# ASP.NET MVC and Automatic RESTful Features

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

Does ASP.NET MVC have anything like the RESTful out-of-the-box features like Ruby on Rails 2.0?
For example: [cURL and Your Rails 2 App](http://www.viget.com/extend/curl-and-your-rails-2-app/)

I think this is the built in REST access to your Models. Since models can be implemented in different ways in ASP.NET MVC is there a feature like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) open source project there is a class called [SimplyRestfulRouteHandler](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SimplyRestfulRouting&referringTitle=Documentation).  Using this class you can add routes to your site that will follow the REST approach.

Here is a good [post](http://kevinortman.blogspot.com/2008/04/simplyrestfulroutehandler-sample.html) on how you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you'll come to this that I know of right now is some of the work Rob Conery is doing like this:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-mvc-scaffold-addin/

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it provides what you want via scaffolding instead of the cURL type implementation.

Comment: +1 - I have been meaning to give SubSonic another shot. Its been at least 2 years since the last time I looked at it.